Node js mysql map result to model
I am new to nodejs (typescript) and I am trying to retrieve data from an mysql database and map this to my model.
But when I log my object later I can see all field of the database entity and not only the fields of my model.
How can I map a result set of a query to a model?
The database table has many columns, but my model has only two attributes. My expectation is to have only these two attributes as a result of my getUserById Method.
Here is my code:
export interface User extends RowDataPacket {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

And the query:
    export class UserService {
      async getUserById(id: string) {
        const [data] = await connection.query<User[]>("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", [id]);
        return data[0];
      }
   }

How can I map the result properly?

Without involving some kind of mapping framework that doesn’t come with base mysql2, mapping database rows to new data types is something you do on a case-by-case basis.
In this case, instead of selecting all the fields with SELECT *, select the fields you want:
SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id = ?


Thanks for the info. I will try that. I was expecting to have this mapping feature out of the box.
